# DBPedia queries very slow

Tags: performance, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I have some very basic DBpedia queries that are responding very slowly. I am not sure if this is a performance problem with DBpedia.org itself. For instance, the following DBpedia query takes anywhere between 2 to 4 secs for me, which my web terms is pretty slow:

```
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbp2: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT ?image ?thumbnail ?abstract WHERE {
  dbp:Hrithik_Roshan foaf:depiction ?image .
  dbp:Hrithik_Roshan dbp2:thumbnail ?thumbnail .
  dbp:Hrithik_Roshan dbp2:abstract ?abstract .
  FILTER (LANG(?abstract) = "en")
}
```

[link to live results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20dbp%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbp2%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20foaf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fimage%20%3Fthumbnail%20%3Fabstract%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20dbp%3AHrithik_Roshan%20foaf%3Adepiction%20%3Fimage%20.%0D%0A%20%20dbp%3AHrithik_Roshan%20dbp2%3Athumbnail%20%3Fthumbnail%20.%0D%0A%20%20dbp%3AHrithik_Roshan%20dbp2%3Aabstract%20%3Fabstract%20.%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20(LANG(%3Fabstract)%20%3D%20%22en%22)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml)

Similar queries in freebase respond within 250ms. Is there any alternative endpoint for DBpedia which performs better?

Comment: DBpedia response time seems to be a bit hit and miss.  About six hours ago when I checked, the query in the question timed out for me, but now I get an almost immediate response.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Do you know of any alternative endpoints where i can query.

Comment: I wish I knew of some DBpedia mirrors. :)  However, you can [download](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads38) the data and run queries locally.  It requires some disk space, yes, but you don't have to worry about the public endpoint getting choked up or being completely unavailable.

Comment: Anyone can set up their own DBpedia mirror via a [pre-configured AWS AMI](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtPayAsYouGoEBSBackedAMIDBpedia2015) (yes, it costs money), among other options. Or you could consider [donating toward improvements to the public endpoint and other infrastructure](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/get-involved) and such...

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue likely has to do with whether or not a particular query or portion of a query is currently in memory... i.e. it was run recently.

DBPEDIA is relatively flat compared to some other RDF databases and contains massively huge amounts of data. So, you should always consider that you may be at risk of accidentally asking for way too much data with the query..

Comment: 1) I am not sure if its about the data being in memory, because when I face this issue, I face it consistently for long times (tested 60 calls in 15 mins, still slow)
2) My query is one of the simpler queries, it just asks the image and abstract of the topic

Comment: I'm not sure how much that sort of locality matters either, but even if you run something 60 times in 15 minutes, someone _else_ could be running a whole lot more.

Comment: you both make good points. I'll ask some of my coworkers what they think and get back to you.